# How to merge two dataframes and keep the non -nan values in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

df1

```
0      Name       phone     Marks

1      mark       1225      20.0

2     charles     165498    36.5

3     oscar       1567      nan

4     bucky       13579     22.0

5     austin      13654     nan
```

df2

```
0      Name       phone     Marks

1      mark       1225      nan

2     charles     165498    nan

3     oscar       1567      25,64,65,78,32

4     bucky       13579     22.0

5     austin      13654     21,989,3,48,6357,649,2
```

How to merge  these two df in this way

```
0      Name       phone     Marks

1      mark       1225      20.0

2     charles     165498    36.5

3     oscar       1567      25,64,65,78,32

4     bucky       13579     22.0

5     austin      13654     21,989,3,48,6357,649,2
```

If i try merge left. I'll miss out  oscar and austin marks,  if i try right i'll miss out mark and charles marks. Tried outer also, but could'nt figure them out

How to merge them based on Names ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Output:

```
0     Name   phone                   Marks
1     mark    1225                      20
2  charles  165498                    36.5
3    oscar    1567          25,64,65,78,32
4    bucky   13579                    22.0
5   austin   13654  21,989,3,48,6357,649,2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easier to achieve with [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [None, 0], 'B': [None, 4]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [3, 3]})
 df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can also use,
df1.fillna(df2.fillna(df1))
```